# How do I stack raster files in R?

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I am trying to perform a raster stack using three spatial raster that are in .grd format, in R using the dismo package.The three grid files are in the path "D:~" . I am using this code,

```
files= list.files(path = "D:~",pattern = 'grd',full.names = TRUE)
```

the error output am getting is

> Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Can anyone help? thanks in advance

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the output of `list.files(path = "D:~",pattern = 'grd',full.names = TRUE)` is `Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Answer (score 5):

If the files are in sub-directories then you can use `recursive=TRUE`:

```
files <- list.files(path="D:", pattern="grd", all.files=FALSE, full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
s <- stack(files)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the stack function from the raster package:

```
files=c("layer1.grd", "layer2.grd", "layer3.grd") 
library(raster)
raster_stack=stack(files)
```